# Sum over rows (but not all), give other rows default value

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have following dataframe (but keep in mind this could have 100+ rows and columns):

[image: table]

I only want to sum the values of some rows that met a condition, in this case of the rows that have a **2** for **stream**. For the other rows I want them to get a default value, for example **0**.

This is what I tried:

```
cols = [col for col in dataFrame.columns if col != 'stream']
dataFrame.loc[dataFrame['stream'] == 2, cols].sum(axis=1)
```

But it doesn't get the result I want. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are very close, you need only add new column `sum` and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `0`:

```
cols = [col for col in df1.columns if col != 'stream']
print cols
['feat', 'another_feat']

df1['sum'] = df1.loc[df1['stream'] == 2, cols ].sum(axis=1)
df1['sum'] = df1['sum'].fillna(0)
print df1
   stream  feat  another_feat   sum
a       1     8             4   0.0
b       2     5             5  10.0
c       2     7             7  14.0
d       3     3             2   0.0
```

If all values are `int`, last you can cast `float` to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df1['sum'] = df1['sum'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print df1
   stream  feat  another_feat  sum
a       1     8             4    0
b       2     5             5   10
c       2     7             7   14
d       3     3             2    0
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['sum'] = np.where(df1['stream'] == 2, df1[cols].sum(axis=1), 0)
print df1
   stream  feat  another_feat  sum
a       1     8             4    0
b       2     5             5   10
c       2     7             7   14
d       3     3             2    0
```

Comment: Thanks again man, it works, great job! And thanks for the info about casting, will probably need that later on.

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!